# Not writing to MySQL database correctly

Tags: php, mysql

I have set up an auto-donation feature for a website, but the data is not being written into the database when the IPN is verified by paypal. The IPN log is written to the webhost and it says the payment is verified, but there is no data being written to the database.

Here's the small snippet that handles the ipn

```
  if ($p->validate_ipn()) {

     $fh = fopen(".ipn", "a");
     fwrite($fh, print_r($p->ipn_data, true));
     fclose($fh);

     if($p->ipn_data["payment_status"] != "Completed") die();

     if($p->ipn_data["mc_gross"] > 0) {
         $user = $p->ipn_data["custom"];
         $date = $p->ipn_data["payment_date"];
         $prodid = $p->ipn_data["item_number"];
         $amount = $p->ipn_data["mc_gross"];
         $amountTickets = 1;

         //$user = str_replace("-", "_", $user);
         //$user = str_replace(" ", "_", $user);
         $user = str_replace("-", " ", $user);
         $user = str_replace("_", " ", $user);
         $user = mysql_real_escape_string($user);
         $conn = mysql_connect("localhost", "USERNAME", "PASSWORD");
         mysql_select_db('web_donations', $conn);
         mysql_query("INSERT INTO donation (username, time, productid, price, tickets) VALUES ('" . $user . "', '" . $date . "', '" . $prodid . "', " . $amount . ", " . $amountTickets . ");");
         $fh = fopen(".ipnerr", "a");
         fwrite($fh, mysql_error());
         fclose($fh);
         mysql_close($conn);
      }
  }
```

I don't receive any errors. Just the data is not being written to the database, everything else is verified in the logs.

Edit: I have solved the issue, the issue was this:

```
 if($p->ipn_data["payment_status"] != "Completed") die();
```

The payments were held in pending which means it would never pass this stage

Comment: I'll bet one of the fields has index as unique, and you try to insert a value already present.

Comment: Make the script to echo the mysql_query, and try running that query in phpmyadmin to see whats the error.Or, log the mysql query being run into a file or so, and run it manually in phpmyadmin.

Comment: why don't you exit your query to find why?

Comment: No errors are being thrown, I've tried running the query manually in phpmyadmin and it works fine. I've tried deleting the table and creating a new one and still nothing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are some things that you have do in order for this to work, some unrelated to PHP programming, so, i will not post source code. Your comments about it working when invoked manually suggest that the culplrit is the SSL certificate.

Been there! done that!

1.- Make sure your website has a SSL certificate installed. PayPal requires the website to be able to have support for HTTPS instead of just HTTP, it sends the payment notification via HTTPS.

2.- If you are using a saved button Make sure the button points to the correct HTTPS notification url.

3.- There is no way you can read the errors with error_reporting() as sugested, because this is a transaction between PayPal and your website. The only thing you can do is to save somewhere (a file for example) a "flag" to see if the URL was invoked by PayPal, which wont do unless you do the step 1 and 2.

I will add more points if i remember, for now check those. :)

Comment: Thanks. There is a SSL certificate and the ipn is coming back as verified, the payment is verified in the logs. The only problem is that the data is not put into the database so I'm assuming it's an issue with  the way I have done the mysql

Comment: I have some code that works perfectly with PayPal IPN that i can provide you with, but it uses a framework slightly different than the one you are using. Can you post the URL were i can try your php? Or some other, (rename it! because PayPal notification URL's is not a very good idea.

Comment: Try $fh = fopen("somefile.txt", "w+"); instead $fh = fopen(".ipn", "a"); perhaps there IS an error in the database query but there is also an error in the file creation and cannot be writen to file.

Comment: I tried, it doesn't create the file after the query

Comment: Then it is settled!!!. Your PayPal IPN is not being validated correctly. The next step is to remove this line: if ($p->validate_ipn()) { 

let the code execute without that, and save to file the a string from the Paypal IPN, for example: 

    fwrite($fh, $_REQUEST["payment_date"]);

 If the line is written correctly, the IPN notificatioj is coming trough, but the verification is messing, probably because an error in the syntax of the notification URL, is it correctly formatted in your paypal button?

Comment: Thanks for the help! I solved the problem. It was that the payments were pending rather than being completed.